# PostgreSQL: Need to perform Row operation

Tags: sql, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I'm new with PostgreSQL. I would like to perform a row operation on my table.
For example consider this table output :

```
Record  | Accesories |    Used
Joy     | Laptop     |     500
Joy     | Android    |     270
Stuart  | Laptop     |     300
Stuart  | Android    |      25
```

I would like to display the name of "Record" for which Android usage is upto 10% of Laptop.IN  this case its Joy who is using Android device upto 10% of Laptop. Mathematical calculation we did : `(270/500)*100=54%` . I want same operation to be done in my table. Table is having more than 1lac such record.
Can someone help me for framing query for same. Thanks

Comment: read about joins - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp. When you done, read about indexes and how it help to make your joins faster. After that, you'll write this query easily

Comment: Thanks for response. But Even by learning Joins i don't get much idea on it. I tried Self join too. I have only one table in my database from which i need to fetch result.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    T1.Record
from Table1 as T1
    inner join Table1 as T2 on T2.Record = T1.Record
where
    T1.Accesories = 'Android' and T2.Accesories = 'Laptop' and
    (T1.Used::float / T2.Used * 100)::int > 10
```

Actually what's done here - we get all rows from `Table1` where `Accesories = 'Android'` and then for each record we trying to find records where Record = Record from chosen row and `Accesories = 'Laptop'` (note that if `Record, Accesories` is not unique key for your table, you could end up with duplicate rows). After that, all you need it's just calculate value and filter out rows which're not satisfy condition (by adding this to `where` clause).

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/dc23e/4)</kbd>**

Comment: "Try to understand", when said about a bunch of code with not a word of explanation, is not very helpful. :)

Comment: @AndriyM well played, I'll add explanation